# Python Twisted multiple clients error in factory/protocol

Tags: python, runtime-error, twisted

I am getting error "exceptions.AttributeError: MyServerFactory instance has no attribute 'isLeaf'"

My code is as below, It was working for single client connection, then i tried making changes for multiple clients but now it fails.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
###### for autogeneration please do not write new imports above this line #########
from twisted.web import xmlrpc, server
import twisted
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

PORT = 2222
SERVER_INFO = 'testing concurrency'
class TwiestedServer(xmlrpc.XMLRPC, Protocol):
    """
    An example of using you own policy to fetch the handler
    """
    """
    =======================================================
    Function name : __init__
    Purpose       : Initialize libraries and add functions
    Inputs        : self
                    args
                    kwargs
    Outputs       : none
    =======================================================
    """
    def __init__(self,factory):
        xmlrpc.XMLRPC.__init__(self)
        # init libraries

        self._procedureToCallable = {}
        self.factory = factory

        # add functions
        self._procedureToCallable = {
            'get_server_info':      self.get_server_info,
        }

    """
    =======================================================
    Function name : __dir__
    Purpose       : 
    Inputs        : self
    Outputs       : none
    =======================================================
    """
    def __dir__(self):
        dir_list1 = [k for k in self.__dict__]
        dir_list2 = [k for k in self._procedureToCallable]
        dir_list = dir_list1 + dir_list2
        return dir_list

    def fio(self,x):
        if x == 1 or x == 2:
           return 1
    else:
        return self.fio(x-1) + self.fio (x-2)

    """
    =======================================================
    Function name : get_server_info
    Purpose       : Get information about server
    Inputs        : self
    Outputs       : none
    =======================================================
    """
    def get_server_info(self,x):

        return self.fio(x)
        #return SERVER_INFO

    """
    =======================================================
    Function name : lookupProcedure
    Purpose       : Check if proceedure that has to be called
                    is available in class
    Inputs        : self
                    procedurePath
    Outputs       : none
    =======================================================
    """
    def lookupProcedure(self, procedurePath):
        try:
            return self._procedureToCallable[procedurePath]
        except KeyError, e:
            raise xmlrpc.NoSuchFunction(self.NOT_FOUND,
                        "procedure %s not found" % procedurePath)

    """
    =======================================================
    Function name : direct_server_method
    Purpose       : Display that one is present on server
                    library
    Inputs        : self
    Outputs       : none
    =======================================================
    """
    def direct_server_method(self):
        return "I am direct on server library"

    """
    =======================================================
    Function name : listProcedures
    Purpose       : 
    Inputs        : self
    Outputs       : none
    =======================================================
    """
    def listProcedures(self):
        """
        Since we override lookupProcedure, its suggested to override
        listProcedures too.
        """

        return self.__dir__()
    """
    =======================================================
    Function name : _ebRender
    Purpose       : To throw error
    Inputs        : self
                    failure
    Outputs       : Failure value
    =======================================================
    """
    def _ebRender(self, failure):

        #if isinstance(failure.value, xmlrpc.Fault):
        #    return failure.value
        return xmlrpc.Fault(str(failure), "error")

class MyServerFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return TwiestedServer(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
        r = MyServerFactory()
        reactor.listenTCP(PORT, server.Site(r))
        reactor.run()
    except twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError as e:
        sys.stderr.write(str(e))
        sys.exit(98)
```

We've used fio function to test the concurrency of clients as fio(40) takes around 2-3 mins, meanwhile the server should resolve fio(3).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only guess that the function server.Site() expects "isLeaf" on your instance of MyServerFactory. The code that you've listed here actually isn't that relevant to your problem. Clearly, based on that class definition, Python is correct -- there is no attribute isLeaf.

Comment: @Neel : You are right, server.Site() was expecting "isLeaf", now passing the object directly to reactor.listenTCP(PORT, MyServerFactory()) this works (in a sense, i mean there is no error), but the called client doesn't receive the output. from code....
"return self.fio(x)"...client keep n waiting for the output.
How to return the function value to the calling client..?